# innerText returns value of "value" attribute in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, innertext

When I set value of an element via script

`textAreaObject.value = "some text"`

and try to get text of this object via `textObject.innerText` Internet Explorer 11 returns "some text" but chrome does not.

According to this link https://caniuse.com/innertext
there is a known issue of IE 11 incorrectly returning value of placeholder attribute via innerText, but I could not find anything about same happening for value attribute. Is this a bug in IE11?

**Example chrome:**

[image]

**Example IE:**(same html file)

[image]

Comment: No matter what IE does, `.innerText` is not the way to get the contents of a `<textarea>`.  The `.value` property is correct.

Comment: Not an answer but A very rare case where IE executes something and chrome doesn't, haven't seen an argument like this for a while. So I tend to believe its an IE bug

Comment: IE is currently way below 1% of the market, and I doubt that behaviors like this will ever be fixed.

Comment: You did not define a placeholder.

Comment: thanks @Pointy and @ Tushar, only value property is correct way to get content. Even if I set text through innerText, I can only get content through value property. So I am using value now.